# Netbeans and rails error: bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- script/rails (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, netbeans, ruby-on-rails-4, netbeans-7

When I'm trying to launch Rails console on netbeans 7.4 after I create project I get `/home/mati/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- script/rails (LoadError)` , but this file exists. I was looking here [Rails on Netbeans: Uncaught exception: no such file to load -- script/server or script/console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188963/rails-on-netbeans-uncaught-exception-no-such-file-to-load-script-server-or) but it didn't really help. Is there something else I could try?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a symbolic link  as below on terminal:

```
ln -s ./bin ./script
```

This is because in Rails 4 `script` directory has been moved to `bin`.

Comment: thanks, that changed something. Now I got 'Could not find gem 'sdoc (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)'

Comment: Do you have `require: false` for gem sdoc in Gemfile?

Comment: Remove `require: false` and it should run like a champ.

Comment: When I run in console "gem list" I can see that sdoc is installed. I removed 'require: false' but netbeans still throws same error.

Comment: run `bundle install` first.

Comment: Thanks for patience. I've run this, and right now: 'spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find sprockets-2.11.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)'. It's amazing how hard it is to run rails on netbeans..

Comment: Ok, I have absolutely no idea why but mysql gem was causing failures. Changed it to sqlite3 and everything works. Any chance You know how to solve issue with installing mysql2 gem?

Comment: I haven't used mysql gem. I would recommend posting another question for `installing mysql gem` so some mysql expert can assist you.

Comment: Is there any permanent solution for this problem, every time when I run my project from NetBean I need to run this command from terminal.

Comment: I am getting same exception in `NetBeans` installed on `Windows`. Can anybody guide on how to fix this ? I am using `Rails 4` and it is installed in `C:\RailsInstaller` which contains following folders within it: `DevKit`, `Git`, `Ruby2.1.0` and `scripts`.

Comment: It's ok now ! Geat !